# Disable form rising to the top

Tags: forms, delphi, z-order

I want a form that when I set at the bottom of the z-order it stays there. I tried:

```
SetWindowPos(Handle,HWND_BOTTOM,Left,Top,Width,Height,SWP_NOZORDER);
```

and when I overlap it with some other apps it stays at the bottom as I need. However when I click on it, it rises to the top. I then tried:

```
SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, Left, Top, Width, Height,
             SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOZORDER);
```

and various other switches from this website...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx

But it still rises to the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SetWindowPos` sets the position of a window only when it is called, it does not establish a state. Handling [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the correct way to do this:

> While this message is being processed, modifying any of the values in
>   WINDOWPOS affects the window's new size, position, or place in the Z
>   order. An application can prevent changes to the window by setting or
>   clearing the appropriate bits in the flags member of WINDOWPOS.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    procedure WindowPosChanging(var Msg: TWMWindowPosMsg);
        message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  end;

..

procedure TForm1.WindowPosChanging(var Msg: TWMWindowPosMsg);
begin
  if Msg.WindowPos.flags and SWP_NOZORDER = 0 then
    Msg.WindowPos.hwndInsertAfter := HWND_BOTTOM;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thank Sertac, I will give that try. "only when it is called," OK, that makes sense and I can now understand the current behavior of SetWindowPos.

Comment: Sertac, sorry for the delay getting back. I had to do it in two steps.     SetWindowPos(frmBottom.Handle,HWND_BOTTOM,0,0,Screen.Width,Screen.Height-myTaskbarHeight,SWP_SHOWWINDOW); within the MainForm, then after that use your Message call within the frmBottom and it works fine. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it, but you might get somewhere trapping the message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, and twiddling with Z order. Could get complicated though and I personally would find it irritatingly non-standard.

A menu option equivalent to cacsade but with a z-order sort might be a better option, I mean if they clicked on it they expect to see it.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I agree with your "non-standard" comment and any click would be an inadvertent one with nothing expected to happen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Out of instinct, I wouldn't trust that the app will always work as you expect. Other applications may have a much more strict method of forcefully bringing its self in front of yours, or vice-versa in your case, sending it to the back. For example, a timer which repeatedly sends the window to the back. Then if you have two of such apps layered, you would watch them fight each other, basically flickering back and forth. In the end, I wouldn't count on a permanent 100% solution for this because you never know what other applications might do to override yours.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, it was the Timer approach that got me asking here. I had a TTimer set at 5-msec, but the flickering proved a problem as you surmised.